# UITableView Translation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to compensate the bouncing effect of the tableView for the need of an animation. I have this code in `scrollViewDidScroll:` :

```
if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0) {

    //Scale a subview of my topCell
    CGFloat scale = 1 + (abs(MIN(scrollView.contentOffset.y,0))/self.tableView.frame.size.height);
    [topCell scaleCellWithFloat:scale];

    //Compensate the bouncing effect            
    self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, MIN(scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0));
}
```

The problem is that the bottom of the tableView is going up. Any idea how to fix this